# Unable to sync Kontact with Google Contacts with Kubuntu 17.04

Tags: kubuntu, kde, sync, google

akonadi-kde-resource-googledata seems to be unable to sync.
I'm looking for a way to sync Kontact with Google Contacts.
I was able to do it on previous releases.

Akonadi is working. I'm looking for a Kontact plugin which is able to sync with google.

Answer (score 0):

I use Kontact 5.4.3 with Kubuntu 17.04 and it syncs my google contacts, gmail and google calendar.  It might be helpful to install the KDE PIM 16.12.3 update.

http://kubuntu.org/news/kde-pim-update-now-available-for-zesty-zapus-17-04/

Even without the latest update, it still syncs with google. In Kontact, go to Contacts.  If your gmail account is listed under Address Books, right click and select Address Book Properties.  Check Enable interval refresh and set your Refresh interval. If your gmail account is not listed, right click in the Address Books box and select Add Address Book.